# flowplayer recommend other videos

Tags: flash, flowplayer

I want to show related video's in flowplayer at the end of the video. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you who gave downvote after 3 years :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a related plugin, but I haven't looked at it myself and can't find any documentation on the flowplayer.org site.  You could take a look at this and see if you can get it working: http://code.google.com/p/flowplayer-plugins/source/browse/#svn/flash/related/trunk/example